# Need advice on inserting data into sqlite database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, insert, structure

I need some pointers with the database that I am creating. I have many persons and each person has many items. My code does: For each item that the person have it inserts the person name, last name, id, email and item into a row in a database. So for each person's individual item it inserts that person and it's item into a row in a database.

So in the end, I have many of the same persons with different items in the database.

Example of how my database looks after I have inserted data:

```
FirstName:   LastName:   Item:
John         Doe         Table
John         Doe         Chair
John         Doe         Laptop
Sarah        Jordan      Mouse
Sarah        Jordan      Keybord
```

This data structure causes problems later in my program. I would like to know if there is a way that I can only insert the person's name and last name once with multiple items for that person, or are there any other better ways to insert the data?

Thanx for your help in advance.

Comment: I think you should first read a tutorial about database normalization

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you need multiple tables like below

```
+-----------+     +--------------+     +--------------+
| Person    |     | personItems  |     | Items        |
+-----------+     +--------------+     +--------------+
| Person_id |1-|  | Item_id      |*---1| Item_id      |
|Person_name|  |-*| Person_id    |     | Item_name    |
+-----------+     |              |     +--------------+
                  +--------------+
```